# Is there a Chrome extension that will save all viewed resources whose URL match a given expression?

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-extensions, browser-cache

For example, if I wanted to save all PNG files that I come across in Wikipedia articles, I could enter

```
*.wikipedia.org/*.png
```

Or if I wanted to save any file with pony in the filename, I could use

```
*pony*
```

Does a Chrome extension that provides this functionality exist?  Using either wildcards or full-fledged regular expressions for the pattern matching is fairly immaterial.

Comment: nit: Those are wild-card or glob expressions. Do you want them or regexes? (not that I have an answer for you)

Comment: Very fine nit indeed.

Comment: I realize now that most extensions I've seen that do pattern matching use wildcards.

Comment: Could elaborate on which extensions do pattern matching with wildcards? - I haven't come across any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, I haven't found an extension, but **`in linux`** you *could* raid google-chrome's cache for the images - if only from 1 site, clear your cache first then load the pages you want to get images from.

To find google's cache -- use your file manager (thunar / nautilus / whatever ) to navigate to /home/yourusername/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache (This is a hidden folder)

Now that you know where all those downloaded images and stuffs have gone lets see if we can get them out of there, and rename them with proper extensions (your gonna have to rename each one to something comprehensible) HERE Goes... -->

Example 1: to find JPEG files under /home/yourusername/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache

open a terminal...
cd /home/yourusername/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache

```
 find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | grep -i JPEG | awk {'print $1'} | sed 's/^..//g' | sed 's/.$//g' > /tmp/FILESTOMOVE.txt
```

**The command explained...**

1. `find -type f`  = find files
2. `xarg -0 file -i` = output the mime type
3. `grep -i JPEG` = only show give me JPEG files
4. `awk {'print $1'} | sed 's/^..//g' | sed 's/.$//g'` = tidy up file names
5. `> /tmp/FILESTOMOVE.txt` = create a filelist for moving.

   Just change `grep -i JPEG` to PNG or GIF or FLASH etc --- the -i flag denotes case-insensitive (so you could just use grep -i jpeg / png / gif etc)

Now you have a list of files... I have a little command I use to move that list to somewhere.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
mkdir -p /home/yourusername/Downloads/saved_from_google_cache/
if [ -f /tmp/FILESTOMOVE.txt ];then
     cat /tmp/FILESTOMOVE.txt |
     while read newfile; 
     do
        mv $newfile /home/yourusername/Downloads/saved_from_google_cache/
    done
fi
```

Save it as `move_google_cached` in /usr/bin or /usr/sbin and `chmod 755 move_google_cached`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a Perl script using [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm).  It was pretty easy using the [examples](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Proxy/lib/HTTP/Proxy/BodyFilter/save.pm), but there is the hassle of changing your proxy settings every time you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you asked for, but I think it bears mentioning. The best extension I have seen is actually for Firefox and it's called [BatchDownload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/batchdownload-10837/). It provides wildcards to generate download URLs (like curl) and will also allow you to do substring matching to all the links on a given page. I find it quite useful.